# IntelliJ Scala worksheet - missing arguments for method main in object

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm new to both Scala and IntelliJ, and have been tinkering with both in my spare time for the past couple of weeks. I'm not sure if the error I'm getting is Scala syntax, or the way I have my project structured, so I'll walk through both...

I created a new project ( Scala > Scala : Simple module with attached Scala SDK. )

And I laid out my project like this, with a worksheet next to my classes under source.

```
src
|- main.scala.finance
|  |- dao
|  |  |- BudgetActualDao
|  |- model
|  |  |- Transaction
|  |  |- etc...
|- worksheet.sc
```

`BudgetActualDao` is basically a mock data class with a private list of `Transactions` and a `list` method that returns them. I created it from my checking & credit cards so that I would have good data to analyze as I experimented with the language.

Anyways, in `worksheet.sc` I just have an import statement

```
import main.scala.finance.dao.BudgetActualDao
```

And the errors I'm getting are these:

```
Error:missing arguments for method main in object A$A20;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied    function
import main.scala.finance.dao.BudgetActualDao
   ^

Error:(7, 50) missing arguments for method main in object A$A20;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
println(MacroPrinter211.printImportInfo({import main.scala.finance.dao.BudgetActualDao;}))
                                            ^
```

I've successfully imported and used basic Java classes in my worksheet before (StringBuilder, LocalDate, etc.) without it whining - so what is the worksheet having a problem with now? Is it something about the way the project is structured / named?

**Edited to add class implementations:**

`BudgetActualDao` looks like this (List is truncated as it's quite long.)

```
package main.scala.finance.dao

import java.time._
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import main.scala.finance.model.budget.{Credit, Debit, Category, Transaction}

class BudgetActualDao {

  def list()  = {
    transactions
  }

  private val transactions = List[Transaction](
    new Credit(date("12/11/2015"), "AMAZON.COM", Category.GIFT, 63.68),
    new Credit(date("12/10/2015"), "LAREDOS", Category.DINING, 10),
    ...
  )

  private val dtf:DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")
  private def date(value:String) : LocalDate = {
    LocalDate.parse(value, dtf)
  }
}
```

Note, `Transaction` is a trait with two classes, `Credit` and `Debit` extending it.

`Category` is an object following an enum pattern I dug up somewhere. It looks like this:

```
object Category extends Enumeration {
  val CLOTHING = EnumVal("Clothing")
  val DINING = EnumVal("Dining")
  val GROCERY = EnumVal("Groceries")
  ... etc

  protected case class EnumVal(name:String) extends super.Val()
  implicit def convert(value:Value) = value.asInstanceOf[EnumVal]
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run a method in an object `A` inside the of body of the class  `main.scala.finance.dao.BudgetActualDao`.  Could you post the Code of your DAO?

Comment: I added that class, and a couple other. I did have a compile error I hadn't caught, but after fixing it I still have the same two errors in the worksheet. They seem to be linked to the import statement, because I get them even if the import is the _only_ statement in my worksheet.sc

I've also tried other variations of import, such as `import main.scala.finance.dao._` to no difference. 

I'm assuming the problem is in the worksheet itself somehow, and not the other classes. I thought .sc files were wrapped in an object with a main method, or something similar.

Comment: I would check for `val` in `objects` contained in import `main.scala.finance.dao.BudgetActualDao`. For testing you could change the `val` to `def` so that they will not get executed.